# Why would Hermione be worried about question 14 b?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

In Chapter Sixteen of *Philosopher’s Stone* Hermione is supposed to pretend to be waiting for Flitwick to discuss her exam:

> "It's obvious," said Ron. "You can pretend to be waiting for Professor Flitwick, you know." He put on a high voice, "'Oh Professor Flitwick, I'm so worried, I think I got question fourteen b wrong....'"

Yet after she leaves the staff room (without talking to Flitwick) she tells Harry and Ron that she already got her score from Flitwick:

> "Not if I can help it," said Hermione grimly. "Flitwick told me in secret that I got a hundred and twelve percent on his exam. They're not throwing me out after that."

If she already knew that she got 112% why would she be worried about getting question 14 b wrong? I know that she was only supposed to *pretend* to be worried, but how would that act be believable when Flitwick would just say that they had already discussed her exam?

Comment: _Snape_ didn't know that...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath But Hermione couldn’t discuss that issue with Flitwick. So it wouldn’t actually work if Snape called her out on it (as he did) or if Flitwick was there.

Comment: We don't know that Flitwick didn't tell her after the fact. Also, Ron was just making something up randomly. Hermione could have easily planned to do something else. It seems to me that Ron just wanted to make fun of her while making a half-good plan... This doesn't seem to be a valid question. -1

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath There was no time for Flitwick to tell her after the fact. She went straight to the common room and that’s when she told Harry and Ron about the 112%. Also, we might expect Hermione to point out that Ron’s idea wouldn’t work.

Comment: Flitwick cornering Hermione on her way back? Flitwick telling Hermione beforehand, but Hermione doesn't actually refute Ron's mockery? There are several plausible reasons...

Comment: Valorum's answer is correct, but hypothetically speaking, why wouldn't she be worried about getting14b wrong?  I mean, 112% is good and all, but 113% is even better ...

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think that raises the more basic question of what it means to get 112% on an exam.

Answer (score 17):

This isn't Hermione expressing concern about that question, it's Ron mocking her by making up a '*Hermione-esque*' reason that she might be hanging around outside of a teacher's room.

> *‘It’s obvious,’* said Ron. *‘You can pretend to be waiting for Professor Flitwick, you know.’* **He put on a high voice,** *‘Oh Professor Flitwick, I’m so worried, I think I got question fourteen b wrong …’*

It seems likely that this isn't the first time (nor will it be the last) that she's argued about her marks with the faculty.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

Ron and Harry wanted Hermione to pretend to be worried about question 14b so she had an exuse to stand outside the staff room. Remember that the boys didn't know that she had already recieved her mark in secret. Hermione possibly didn't say anythiing about this flaw in thhe excuse because she wasn't planning on using it. If I recall correctly she told Ron to 'shut up' straight after he suggested it but 'still agreed to stand outside the staff room', which means she had already found another excuse without the flaw and didn't trouble explaining it to the boys.
Apart from that, even if Hermione used that excuse, she is a top student and known to keep worrying about her marks and afraid of failing, so even though she knew she had scored over 100% I do not think Professor Flitwick would have thought it suspicious if she asked about question 14b.

Comment: While possible, I think that most people, if they stretch their memory back to their preteen years, will remember how much fun was had by mocking other people. Especially the mocking done by those who weren't particularly high academic achievers (Ron) of those who were (Hermione). The statement wasn't literally about question 14b (any question number would have done), but in general about her desperate desire for academic perfection.